# Recreating a MySQL database if you have the .frm, .myd and .myi records

Tags: mysql

```
Centos 6.5
MySQL 5.5?
WHM/CPanel
```

WHM/Cpanel seems to be creating mysql directories for each account in the directory /var/lib/mysql

For one of these account, let's call it test, I have the following files (from a backup):

```
ids.frm
ids.myd
ids.myi
```

Is it possible to restore the test account, with this table? Is there a sequence where I create the account using WHM, and then copy the files into the /var/lib/mysql/test directory? I saw an answer on this forum, but it applies to a flat file data directory. My /etc/my.cnf file has no data directory specified.

Answer (score 0):

Those 3 files are the entire knowledge that MySQL has about a MyISAM table.  Put them into a directory and you now have added that table to the database named as the directory.

(There is no simple equivalent for InnoDB tables.)

Comment: What about the ibdata1, ib_logfile0 and iblogfile1